# javascript-generated anchor tags are not visible when jumping to anchor tags on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, url, anchor, hashtag

For a webpage where the anchor tags are inserted into the HTML server-side, I can jump to each anchor tag by either manually changing the hash tag at the end of the URL in the address bar or by having clickable links on the same page (`<a href="#mytag">gotomytag</a>`) that take me to my local anchors without reloading the page.

I have noticed that this won't work if the anchor tags on the page are generated using JavaScript. Unless I'm doing something wrong, I'm about to conclude that JavaScript generated hash-tags aren't visible to navigation by anchor tags included in the URL.

To make things more clear, here's the sequence that doesn't work:

1. Navigate to mysite.com/mypage.php
2. JavaScript right before `</body>` tag adds my anchor tag (`<a name="here"></a>`)
3. I change the URL in the address bar to "mysite.com/mypage.php#here"
4. I expect the browser to navigate to the tag. But it doesn't. Nothing happens as if the tag doesn't exist. If I include the anchor tag added in step 2 on the server side, then this step navigates to the anchor as expected.

Also, I am using the following snippet to create the element which I have confirmed works correctly using the builtin chrome debugger:

```
`var ael = document.createElement('a');
ael.setAttribute('name','here');
someelementinmyhtmldom.appendChild(ael);`
```

I Hope someone here can set me straight or confirm my finding and suggest a work-around.

I'm on Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 on Windows 7.

Thanks.

EDIT: Reason for my initial code not working:
The answer to my question is given in the post below, but if you're interested in why my code wasn't working: I learned that you cannot navigate to an anchor tag that is hidden by other elements! I was placing my anchor element about 50px above where it should have been (using absolute placement) in order to compensate for the sticky menu bar up top and that made my anchor disappear because of overflow:hidden property of its containing element. The solution: make sure you anchor is not covered up either by other elements or because of moving outside of an element whos's overflow is hidden.

Comment: You need to show the JavaScript that is modifying your tag. Make sure you are using `document.createElement`, rather than `.innerHTML = ...`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-name) attribute of the `<a>` element is considered obsolete under HTML5; and now a link fragment/hash serves to link to a specific HTML element via its `id` property.

Comment: @DavidThomas That's a good point (my answer used `id` without even thinking about `name`), but I would think `name` would still work in the vast majority of user agents for backwards compatibility. I could be wrong though, since I've used `id` for quite a while now.

Comment: @Scott: it almost certainly will, but it's best not to rely on an obsolete feature.

Comment: @DavidThomas Absolutely!

Comment: Where, **exactly**, in the page does `<a name="here"></a>` get added? If it is at the bottom of the page, the browser wont' be able to scroll it to the top of the browser window.

Comment: When is that JavaScript that you posted, executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrolling to target anchors (or any `#target`) will be limited to the content on the page. If you are trying to scroll to the bottom of a page, the browser can only scroll so far (i.e. the bottom of the page can't scroll to the top of the window unless the window's height is very small). It's entirely possible that it is working just fine, but your scroll position just isn't reachable.

Taking that off the table, use `id` instead of `name` (as @DavidThomas described in the comments) for best compatibility.

Lastly, because you can now use `id`, your targets no longer have to be limited to hyperlinks. Rather than creating empty anchor elements that you can link to, which just clutters up the DOM, pick an existing element in the DOM and use that.

Barring those issues, the following code creates an `id` on the first paragraph of the document that the hard-coded link at the bottom can scroll to.

As an example though, note that I have also hard-coded a "go to bottom" link at the top and when you click it, you won't see the bottom scroll all the way to the top.

If you create the new element using `document.createElement()` and set up the element's properties using `setAttribute`, there should be no problem.

```js
var thePs = document.querySelectorAll("p");

// Update the first paragraph to have the id that will serve as the target:
thePs[0].setAttribute("id", "top");
```

```css
p:last-of-type{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#bottom">Go to bottom</a>This is a test. This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.</p>

<p>This is a test. This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.</p>

<p>This is a test. This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.</p>

<p>This is a test. This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.</p>

<p>This is a test. This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.</p>

<p>This is a test. This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.</p>

<p>This is a test. This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.</p>

<p>This is a test. This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.</p>

<p><a href="#top">Back to Top</a></p>
<p id="bottom">This is the bottom. I'll never be scrollable to the top of the browser window unless the window's height is very small.</p>
```

Comment: My question has to do with injecting the anchor tag that jumped to using javascript. Your example injects a clickable link using javascript.

Comment: @JackJones Ah, sorry, that wasn't clear. The answer is the same though. Let me adjust my code. Also, please show your JavaScript.

Comment: Also, both variants of hash tags (using name or using id) behave the same in my described flow above.

Comment: In addition, the critical part is being able to jump to a dynamically generated hash tag by modifying the URL in the address bar. Please confirm. Thanks.

Comment: added it to my question. I'm trying to get the format right!!

Comment: Your small example works fine in my environment. I need to figure out the reason mine doesn't work! I should have made this example before posting my question! Thanks.

Comment: @JackJones You're welcome. If this has helped, please up vote it and consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: In summary, dynamically generated anchor tags ARE indeed visible to intra-page navigation and the hastily formed conclusion in my original question was incorrect.